# Strange return value from Google Chrome console

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm studing async JS now and trying this:

```
function printOne() {
  console.log(1);
}
function printTwo() {
  console.log(2);
}

setTimeout(printOne, 1000);
setTimeout(printTwo, 0);
```

In return I got something like this:

<99350

2

1

The question is: what's 99350 mean? I understand that it's something about time, but why does console return it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just the `timeoutID`, the return value from [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

> The returned `timeoutID` is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to `setTimeout()`; this value can be passed to [`WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) to cancel the timeout.
>
> It may be helpful to be aware that `setTimeout()` and [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) share the same pool of IDs, and that `clearTimeout()` and [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) can technically be used interchangeably. For clarity, however, you should try to always match them to avoid confusion when maintaining your code.

```js
function printOne() {
    console.log('printOne', 1);
}

function printTwo() {
    console.log('printTwo', 2);
}

console.log('timeoutID', setTimeout(printOne, 1000));
console.log('timeoutID', setTimeout(printTwo, 0));
```